# Compare differences or ratios of factors by time

Tags: nonparametric, methodology

I observe a process in which particles could be detected on a start point, and sometimes cross a border. So I count the number of particles during the days. Which non-parametric method would you suggest to clarify if the difference or ratio of start and cross border factors is different between two given days?

```
                  Days of observation
Particles         2013-07-22 2013-07-23 2013-07-24 2013-07-25 2013-07-26 2013-07-27 2013-07-28 2013-07-29 2013-07-30 2013-07-31
start             69         297        53         31         34         18         32         255        78         12
crossborder       14         231        45         24         26          6         47         193        66          4
```

Comment: In my opinion chi-squared test is appropriate for that question.

Comment: @O_Devinyak, I am not a profession but $\chi^2$-test sound that the distribution of the teststatistik is $\chi^2$-distribution, and I can suggest that reason why it is a $\chi^2$-distribution came from the assumption of test, that the random variables are normal distributed. In this case my question was about a non parametric test.

Comment: There are no assumption about normal distribution. Moreover, normal distribution cannot be observed for nominal variable you have. The chi-squared test can be viewed as non parametric. However, if you have enough facilities to compute 297!, Fisher exact test may be helpful.

Comment: @O_Devinyak And where the distribution $\chi^2$ comes from, is it a limit distribution?

Comment: Oh! It really comes from normal. However, its usage is justified when cells are >5. I've found this article on nonparametric testing of nominal variables: http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jmva.2009.12.017